# Advertisement management software for a newspaper organization

Tags: software-development, finance, information-management

I'm really looking hard for a reliable software to manage newspaper advertisements together with finance & circulation modules. Does anyone know any good softwares for newspapers to manage advertisements, finance & circulation?

The software must be able do the following:

1. Store the 'release orders' for the sold advertisement spaces i.e., it will have the size of the ad, price, position, client, agent, etc.
2. Bills must be raised when the advertisement is published in the newspaper.
3. When a payment is received, it must be processed and a receipt must be issued.
4. Report generation of the outstanding bills.
5. Basic accounting i.e., ledger, balance sheet, profit and loss.

We currently have a very unreliable custom built software with which we're so tired of bugs. No proper testing was carried out.

Comment: Most likely there will be no such program off the shelf. You write that your current tool thats unreliable is custom build, so I assume paying for the software is fine to you. Do you have an upper limit on how much the software may cost?

Comment: I thought that Finance module was part of any ERP software. I'm not sure what SAP Business one provides out of the box and any additional functions can be added. We've spent a couple of thousands already building the software and I'm not satisfied.